Override Ctrl+n with Typescript
I am searching a way to override Ctrl-N with Typescript. I use Chrome-Browser.
I have tried this:
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown_deleteCurrentLine(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'n') {
       event.preventDefault();

       this.createNewLine();
   }
}

but it will still always open a new Browser-Window.
I hope, someone can help me. Thank you.

Countless millions of developer hours have been wasted trying to prevent users performing certain actions in their browser. The answer is always: don't bother. I can press CTRL+N. I can right click and Open in new Tab/Window. I can press ALT+F+N. I can middle click the icon on the taskbar to open a new browser instance. I can turn off JS and use your site exactly as I like. If there's a reason you need to prevent this behaviour, then I'd suggest you revisit why that is.

I would consider using a different shortcut. I know it's no ideal though
